# why are "flushes" required for bigpipe?

Tags: node.js

https://github.com/jehrhardt/bigpipe-node/blob/master/app.js
http://www.subbu.org/blog/2010/07/bigpipe-done-in-node-js

I've noticed that all implementations of bigpipe need to "flush" the HTML. In other words, something like this always happens:

```
// header n stuff

res.write('<script>function flushHTML(id, html) {'
  + 'document.getElementById(' + id + ').innerHTML = ' + html
  + '};</script>')

// more stuff

// a "pagelet"
res.write('<script>flushHTML(' + someID + ', ' + myHTML + ');</script>')

res.end('</body></html>')
```

Why can't you just `res.write(html)` each section without flushing?

Comment: Upon further reading, it seems people only use flushes to serve content in any order. Just writing the HTML in order should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point is to split big task of generating entire HTML into many small tasks ( aka pagelets ). For example assume you want to send to a browser two things: user details and details of a transaction he just made. Instead of doing both these tasks ( ie loading data from DB ) and sending HTML after that, you would load a user from DB an send it to browser, then load transaction from DB and send it to browser.

This ultimetly leads to a better user experience and faster loading time ( because browser generates HTML chunk by chunk which is more efficient then everything at once ).

Note that this was developed ( or at least widely used by ) Facebook, so read this article for more info:

http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919

Comment: Oh, so you are asking "why script tags"? Probably because you would not preserve order otherwise ( especially in Node.JS, where you can send pagelets in random order ). I can't see any other reason for doing that.

Comment: yeah just figured out thats all its for.